# Cannot see remote branches in WebStorm

Tags: git, intellij-idea, webstorm, git-remote

I have added another remote in WebStorm, but I'm unable to see the list of branches for all remotes, only the "origin" remote is listed:

[image]

Here is my `.git/config`:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
[pull]
    rebase = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:XXX/XXX.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[remote "template"]
    url = git@github.com:XXX/TEMPLATE-XXX.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/template/*
[branch "main"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/main
```

Here is the output of `git branch -a`, which lists all branches (remotes+local)

[image]

So, it looks like I do have 2 remotes configured, but the branches of the "template" remote don't show on WebStorm. Any idea why?

Comment: When I click on Git > Fetch, it "works" but only the remote branches of "origin" are shown in the branches UI, not those of "template".

Comment: I removed the remote, fetched, added it again, and fetched, and it finally worked. I did all through WebStorm, no command line. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally via <kbd>VSC</kbd> -> <kbd>Git</kbd> -> <kbd>Fetch</kbd> would downlod **all remote** branches…

Where do you execute `git branch -a`? In IntelliJ terminal? If no, try via VSC-Settings to fetch all branches.